# How to watch for model changes and update some property in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have the following scenario. I have two Angular components which share the same model.

The first component at some point updates the `shared` model and I'd like to be able to pick that update in my second component. I tried doing something like:

```dartlang
@NgComponent(...)
class MySecondComponent {
  Scope scope;
  NgModel ngModel;
  String someValue;

  MySecondComponent(this.ngModel, this.scope) {
    imagsomeValueeUrl = ngModel.modelValue;
    scope.$watch('ngModel.modelValue', (newValue, oldValue, _this) {
      someValue = newValue;
    });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like I figured it out. I used ```ctrl.ngModel.modelValue``` instead of ```ngModel.modelValue```. Not sure if this is the best way to deal with this use case though....

Answer (score 0):

Use NgModel.render to listen to changes implicitely:

```dart
MySecondComponent(this.ngModel) {
  ngModel.render = (String modelValue) {
    someValue = modelValue;
  }
}
```